# USB3 Hub with Individual Toggles (Switches) for each Port

Tags: usb, hub

Please recommend a USB3 hub with the following features:

1. At least 4 USB3 ports.
2. **Individual toggles (switches) for each port.**
3. No LED lights, unless they can be easily disabled or cleanly obscured with electrical tape.
4. Reliable for data transfer onto USB3 storage devices.
5. Compact size.

The hub can be powered, or non-powered.  Either is fine.

Less expensive is preferred, but not required.

Prefer black, gray, or silver, but any color is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite by far is the [mbeat 7 port](https://www.pccasegear.com/products/18565/mbeat-7-port-usb-3-0-powered-hub-with-switches/) hub.

[image]

1. 4xUSB_3.0 + 3xUSB_2.0 - actually the USB 2's are really handy for incompatible Logitech gear.
2. Individual switches
3. Dull LEDs on the top that can be covered.
4. Good throughput - see my wiring layout below.
5. NOT compact, but its flat, with all ports along the one side - so its good to attach to the back of the table and use as a permanent dock/expansion.

I use the AC adapter, but I just tested it without (I even plugged in an extra USB3-stick to see if I could trip it, and its fine).

Here's my usage to give you an idea of continual bandwith.

> 7_U3 > [USB3 AV breakout box](http://www.displaylink.com/integrated-chipsets/dl-3000) with HDMI, DVI, Analog audio used.
>    6_U3 > USB3 HDD (powered, WD3TB).
>    5_U3 > <kbd>Spare</kbd> (for USB-sticks and the likes).
>    4_U3 > Micro-USB lead for fast-charging my devices.
>    3_U2 > Multi-charger lead for random devices that come across my desk.
>    2_U2 > Logi G100 Keyboard 
>    1_U2 > Logi M100 Mouse

So I use the toggles a lot for disconnecting the HDD or stop charging devices, or to temporarily disconnect phones etc that I am testing.